# PHP MySQL Linking Posts to Users

Tags: php, mysql

I decided to open a new question for this topic, as I have been having issues with it. My blog has a mysql database with the table `posts` complete with a `post_user` field. Each user has a form and can submit a post to a public blog. Once they submit this form, complete with a title and a body, when it is posted on the blog it should say `by Username`. My idea is that I can save the username to the `post_user` in the database upon form submission using `$_SESSION` info, but I am not exactly sure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The form, with the old UNSECURE way of entering the session author, note I am only including session data in the form to display what I am trying to show on a blog post, I don't know how to do it any other way hence my question:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<p>
    <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['username'] ?>" readonly />
</p>
<p>
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" id="userid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['id'] ?>" readonly />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="title">Title: </label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
</p>
<p>
    <textarea name="body" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Post" />
</p>
</form>
```

Code that posts the entry:

```
$posts = get_posts();
foreach($posts as $post)
{
    ?>

    <h2><a href ="blog_read.php?pid=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></a></h2>
    <h4>By <font color="#FF6347"><?php echo $post['user']; ?></a></font> on <?php echo $post['date']; ?></h4> 
    <h4><?php echo $post['total_comments']; ?> comments, last comment <?php echo $post['last_comment']; ?>
    <hr />

    <p><?php echo $post['preview']; ?></p>
    <?php

}

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Post your current schema and any code you have.  This question is too vague to get any real help here.

Comment: The problem above is I do not know how to show the session author of the post in any other way than that unsecure form way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't save the username on the posts table. You should have two separate tables: one for the posts and one for the users, which are linked via a `user_id` field, a.k.a `foreign key`.

This is the way *relational databases*, such as MySQL, operate. This serves a few purposes:

1. You avoid repetition in case of one to many relations, which is exactly your case: one user can post many posts.
2. You use a unique identifier.
3. The information is organised better instead of mixing data together.

The way to tie the tables together when retrieving data is by using a JOIN statement, which links the two tables via the common `user_id` field. It is highly recommended to make this field an index, which would significantly speed up data retrieval. (Think about the difference between finding a certain word or sentence in a book by scanning through each and every page, and finding a chapter using the, well, index)

To sum up, you should have an `id` key in your `$_SESSION` super-global array, which you then insert to the `user_id` field upon post submission.

As for your question, you don't need to send the session data with a hidden input field, because *it will be available even after submission* - after all this is what session is all about. So why convert it to $_POST and expose it publicly?

Comment: Would the field still be hidden, but containing the inserted `user_id` field, rather than the `$_SESSION` value?

Comment: In other words will I still send the user account name with the rest of the form (title, body, etc.)

Comment: As I wrote at the end of my answer, you don't need the form to convey session data from page to page. Also, as stated above, you don't need the account name, only the user id. The rest of the data will be stored in the users table, when the user signs up.

Comment: Still having an issue where I cannot get the username to appear with the blogpost once submitted, however I do know how to JOIN tables.

Comment: Please post it as a separate question with all the relevant code and any errors you may recieve

Comment: Well it's the same question, just getting the post linked to a username. The issue is i do not have a link to the `users` table from the `posts` table, i simply have the id, title, and body of the post. Once I understand how to do that I can use your very well explained join method to finish my task

Comment: Put a field called `user_id` in the posts table (or `author`...). In any case the diatribe on `user_id` was pretty silly. `username` is likely to be unique.

Comment: I did that, but how do I populate this user ID when the form is submitted based on session data??

Comment: Going to bring this to a new question, now that I have the table structure down.